# При изменении данных или скрытии и повторном появлении компонента, контент атрибутов d в path удаляется

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, raphael

Подготовил кусок проекта https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-danilo-1tqnuo?file=/src/App.vue
По клику на "Скрыть" и после снова "Показать" (обычный v-if) в каждом `path` полностью теряется контент атрибута `d`.
Уже пробовал использовать метод https://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/reference.html#Element.remove , для удаления и повторной инициализации. Вешать `key` на компонент тоже не помогает.

Над Raphael js используется маленькая библиотечка RussianMap

Comment: Принципиально использовать `v-if`?

Comment: Нет, это я для примера сделал. Контент даже если к примеру поменять входные чтобы перерисовать карту

Comment: Ну вообще, что Вам мешает взять просто SVG карты и вставить себе, а при наведении просто обработка такая же? Смысла от пакета всё равно нет. При этом такой проблемы точно не должно появляться, если Вы свой код в компоненте выведете.

Comment: Используйте keep-alive: https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/api/#keep-alive